# PrimeNG datatable template returns blank field within angular2 pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with PrimeNG datatables and I faced with next issue. I send api call to get list of clients. This list is array of objects. Each objects has a field companyId. With using angular pipe and defined services inside of this pipe, I'm trying associate particular companyId with company name from array. The logic is pretty simple but for some reason my grid shows me an empty blank.

Could somebody help me to resolve my issue? I appreciate any help

app pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Companies} from "./objects/companies/companies.component";
    @Pipe({
  name: 'CompanyPipe',
})
export class CompanyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  companies: Companies[];
  result: string;

  constructor(private appService: AppServices){}

  transform (value) {
    this.appService.getCompanies()
      .then(response => {
        this.companies = response;
        for (let i = 0; i <  this.companies.length; i ++){
          if (value ==  this.companies[i].id){
            this.result = this.companies[i].name;
          }
        }
        console.log(this.result); // shows correct associated value
        return this.result
      });
  }
```

app component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Clients} from './clients.component';
import {AppServices} from "../../app.services";

export interface Clients {
  id;
  companyId;
  subscriptionStartDate;
  active;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  title = "clients".toUpperCase();
  clients: Clients[];

  constructor(private appService: AppServices) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getClients().then(response => this.clients = response);
  }
```

html

```
<div class="title-toolbar">
  <h3 >{{title}}</h3>
</div>
<p-dataTable>
  <p-column field="companyId" header="Company" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search">
    <template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
      {{row.companyId | CompanyPipe}}
    </template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="subscriptionStartDate" header="Start Date" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search">
    <template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
      {{row.subscriptionStartDate | date:'medium'}}
    </template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="active" header="Active" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" [style]="{'overflow':'visible'}" filterMatchMode="equals" >
    <template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
      <p-dropdown [options]="activity" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
    </template>
    <template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
      {{row.active | ActivePipe}}
    </template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```